# Sequelize update does not work anymore: "Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to update"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

[The official API documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update) suggests using `Model.update` like this:

```
var gid = ...;
var uid = ...;

var values = { gid: gid };
var where = { uid: uid };
myModel.update(values, where)
.then(function() {
    // update callback
});
```

But this gives me: "Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to update".
The docs also mention that this usage is deprecated. Seeing this error makes me think, they already changed it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your link is not linking to the docs

Comment: Thanks @J.Kirk. - Fixed it! It was the right link at some point (a long long time ago) :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apparently, the docs have not been updated yet. But the table's `where` row of [the `Model.update` API docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update) suggests prefixing your selection with `where`, like so:

```
var gid = ...;
var uid = ...;

var values = { 
  gid
};
var selector = { 
  where: {
    uid
  }
};
await myModel.update(values, selector);
// done!
```

And it works!

**UPDATE:**

The docs have since been updated (and the docs have also been moved). Check out [Model.update on docs.sequelize.com](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update). Note that `options.where` is not optional (it is not in brackets []).

Comment: This belongs in their migration guide.

Comment: I wonder why such an important information is not in the doc.. Maybe I shouldn't be using sequelize?

Comment: @SoichiHayashi Actually, it has been added to the docs for a while. I updated my answer with the link :)